# Promise rejected Node js mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i am creating simple registation form node js with mongoDB when i inserted the records in to the database record is not added in to the database.while inserting the records i got the following error.i have created the application based on mvc architecture.

```
  [UnhandledPromiseRejection: This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). The promise rejected with the reason "false".] {
      code: 'ERR_UNHANDLED_REJECTION'
```

what i tried so far i attached below.

**routers**

```
router.route('/user/create').post(userController.createUserControllerFn);
```

**userController.js**

```
var userService = require('./userServices');

var createUserControllerFn = async (req, res) => 
{
    console.log(req.body);
    var status = await userService.createUserDBService(req.body);
    console.log("*************************");
    console.log(status);
    console.log("*************************");

    if (status) {
        res.send({ "status": true, "message": "User created successfully" });
    } else {
        res.send({ "status": false, "message": "Error creating user" });
    }
}
```

**userServices.js**

```
var userModel = require('./userModel');

var key = '123456799asddfffff';

var encryptor = require('simple-encryptor')(key);
module.exports.createUserDBService = (userDetais) => {

   return new Promise(function myFn(resolve, reject) 
   {
       var userModelData = new userModel();
       userModelData.firstname = userDetais.firstname;
       userModelData.lastname = userDetais.lastname;
       userModelData.email = userDetais.email;
       userModelData.password = userDetais.password;
       var encrypted = encryptor.encrypt(userDetais.password);
       userModelData.password = encrypted;
       userModelData.save(function resultHandle(error, result) 
       {
           if (error) 
           {
               reject(false);
           }
            else 
            {
               resolve(true);
           }
       });

   });

}
```

**userModel.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var userSchema = new Schema({

    firstname: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    lastname: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }

});

module.exports = mongoose.model('users', userSchema);
```

Comment: Rejecting a promise with `false` is not the same as resolving it with `false`. You call `await userService.createUserDBService(req.body);` but then expect to get a `false` out of it, while a rejection will instead throw an error. You're not handling the thrown error.

Comment: how to handing the errorrrr

Comment: `...await userService.createUserDBService(req.body)` to `...await userService.createUserDBService(req.body).catch(console.log);`

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions:

1. In controller.js add try...catch
2. In userservice.js instead of rejecting you can `resolve(false)`

1.solution if you did not changed anything in userservice.js

```
var createUserControllerFn = async (req, res) => 
{
try {
    console.log(req.body);
    var status = await userService.createUserDBService(req.body);
    console.log("*************************");
    console.log(status);
    console.log("*************************");
    res.send({ "status": true, "message": "User created successfully" });
} catch(e) {
    res.send({ "status": false, "message": "Error creating user" });
}
```

1. solution if you have changed `reject(false)` to `resolve(false)`

```
var createUserControllerFn = async (req, res) => 
{
try {
    console.log(req.body);
    var status = await userService.createUserDBService(req.body);
    console.log("*************************");
    console.log(status);
    console.log("*************************");
   if(status) {
    return res.send({ "status": true, "message": "User created successfully" });
   } 
   res.send({ "status": false, "message": "Error creating user" });
} catch(e) {
   res.send({ "status": false, "message": "Error creating user" });
}
```

Comment: i did both as you said both but still getting error

Comment: I added the code. verify it once

Comment: ya but Error creating user    displayed user is not added in to the database